# What is the purpose of an extra variable when Babel and Traceur transpile an ES6 destructure?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, destructuring, traceur

Both Babel and Traceur would transpile for the following code

```
obj = {
    fullName: "Peter",
    say() {
        console.log("My name is", this.fullName);
    }
};

let { fullName, say } = obj;
```

as

```
"use strict";

obj = {
  fullName: "Peter",
  say: function say() {
    console.log("My name is", this.fullName);
  }
};
var _obj = obj,
    fullName = _obj.fullName,
    say = _obj.say;
```

(Traceur uses the name `$__1`) the introduction of a new variable `_obj` seems totally unnecessary. What is a reason that they both do that?

Comment: Does your transpile target always allow for destructuring?  Let me rephrase, what is your transpile target?

Comment: Doesn't happen if you add `let obj` while initializing. Something to do with "strict mode" and implicit globals?

Comment: @zero298 the "Presets"? (on the web interface). It is es2015

Comment: @adiga Traceur still does that even when using the `let obj`

Comment: I would guess it's probably the same code that handles destructuring for function parameters, where you very much do need the temp variable.

Comment: BTW running that transpiled code throws an error saying "*obj is not defined*"

Answer (score 3):

When destructuring a variable declared with `var` it is possible to reassign the variable containing the value you are currently destructuring.

```
var foo = { foo: 1, bar: 2 };
var {foo, bar} = foo;
console.log(`foo: ${foo}, bar: ${bar}`);
// outputs "foo: 1, bar: 2"
```

If this were naively transpiled without creating a temporary variable the variable foo would be altered, before the value for bar is retrieved:

```
var foo = { foo: 1, bar: 2 };
var foo = foo.foo;
var bar = foo.bar;
console.log(`foo: ${foo}, bar: ${bar}`);
// outputs "foo: 1, bar: undefined"
```

My guess is that Babel has an optimization where it recognizes this as not necessary with `let` bindings, because then you would have an error at the point of re-binding of the same variable. Evidently Traceur does not have this optimization. I'm not sure why either one wouldn't only use the local variable when the destructured variable is actually being re-bound.